# Translate Google sheet cells to a JS array?

Tags: javascript

How could I get this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zob6BsVAvM0p8IoKxJYGzFoJVhjUynB0h4dZTW74l0s/edit?usp=sharing

to create 3 arrays in javascript?

I'm hoping to turn these cells into:

```js
var animal = ["dog", "cat", "rabbit", "sloth"] ; 
var eats = ["bone", "fish", "carrot", "leaves"] ;
var enjoys = ["fetch", "hunt", "hop", "sleep"] ;
```

But I'm struggling to find an example of this. 
It seems simple in theory, but complex in practise!

so essentially I need to somehow find a way to run

```js
animal[0] = A1;
animal[1] = A4;
animal[2] = A7;
animal[3] = A10;
```

etc

EDIT, 2 hours later: I have managed to get this far, fetching the string from sheets, but cannot get arrays to work: https://jsfiddle.net/sgpascoe/rkxbfou5/2/

EDIT: 25 hours later! I split the string into an array! It wasn't working, as i was splitting by spaces rather than new lines!

I'm sure my code is messy, but I have solved my issue :D I'm so happy!

https://jsfiddle.net/sgpascoe/neyqvk1s/4/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

Comment: this doesn't seem to show anything about javascript referencing a sheet?

Comment: Do you want to categorize from the values of `dog bone fetch cat fish hunt rabbit carrot hop sloth leaves sleep` retrieved from the Spreadsheet to `var animal = ["dog", "cat", "rabbit", "sloth"]; var eats = ["bone", "fish", "carrot", "leaves"]; var enjoys = ["fetch", "hunt", "hop", "sleep"];`?

Comment: yes! that's exactly what I would like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sgpascoe/neyqvk1s/7/

25 hours later! I split the string into an array! It wasn't working, as i was splitting by spaces rather than new lines!

I'm sure my code is messy, but I have solved my issue :D I'm so happy!

I hope this helps anyone looking to convert google sheets to javascript in the future

**HTML**

```
<div id="Displayurl">empty</div>
<div id="DisplayResponse">empty</div>
<div id="DisplayAnimal">empty</div>
<div id="DisplayEat">empty</div>
<div id="DisplayEnjoy">empty</div><br>

<hr>
<br>

<label for="AnimalChoice">Pick Animal (1-4):</label>
<input type="number" id="AnimalChoice" name="AnimalChoice" min="1" max="4" value="1"><br>

<button onclick="example()">Choose this animal</button><br><br>

<h1><div id="DisplayExample"></div></h1>
```

**JS**

```
var UrlDis = document.getElementById("Displayurl"); //shortener
var AryDis = document.getElementById("DisplayResponse"); //shortener
var AniDis = document.getElementById("DisplayAnimal"); //shortener
var EatDis = document.getElementById("DisplayEat"); //shortener
var EnjDis = document.getElementById("DisplayEnjoy"); //shortener
var ExmDis = document.getElementById("DisplayExample"); //shortener

var animals = []; //global variable for array
var eats = []; //global variable for array
var enjoys  = []; //global variable for array

var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTzgC1w0vtUu4lVrGoQdCFYXFWklYKH-espGRvPXOuBBtcpSkvikhzz6d-OHMKFv5svnsMAGgL_vfsg/pub?single=true&gid=0&range=A1:A12&output=csv"; //google sheets url, cells A1 to A12
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
//  console.log( "response is", xmlhttp.responseText ); //log the response
    AniDis.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; //display GSheets response on top line
    var StringOne = xmlhttp.responseText; // push response to string;
    var TotalArray = StringOne.split("\n"); //convert string to master array
animals = new Array (TotalArray[0],TotalArray[3],TotalArray[6],TotalArray[9]).map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '')); //populate independant array
eats = new Array (TotalArray[1],TotalArray[4],TotalArray[7],TotalArray[10]).map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '')); //populate independant array
enjoys = new Array (TotalArray[2],TotalArray[5],TotalArray[8],TotalArray[11]).map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '')); //populate independant array

UrlDis.innerHTML = "<b>Google Sheet URL: </b>" + url;
AryDis.innerHTML = "<b>Master Array: </b>" + TotalArray; //write to html for testing
AniDis.innerHTML = "<b>Animals: </b>" + animals; //write to html for testing
EatDis.innerHTML = "<b>Eats: </b>" + eats; //write to html for testing
EnjDis.innerHTML = "<b>Enjoys: </b>" + enjoys; //write to html for testing

  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function example(){
var AnimalSelection = document.getElementById("AnimalChoice").value; //retrieve the entered number
var adjustednumber = AnimalSelection-1; //reduce by one, to allow for array numbering
ExmDis.innerHTML = "The " + animals[adjustednumber] + " eats " + eats[adjustednumber] + " and loves to " + enjoys[adjustednumber] + "!"
;} //output final sentence
```